# Editing a header with css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I managed to code for a header and a navigation bar however I don't know how to set the elements such as:
Contact me. etc...

I want to seperate them apart and give them icons and align the text to the right.

(I'm using bootstrap4) however nothing seems to be working not even in the css.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-top" id="navbar-toolbar">
  <div class"container-fluid">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li  class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">+97433653399</a style="background-color: #ffff;">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
    </li>
  </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Navbar
    
      
    
    
      
        
          Home (current)
        
        
          Login
        
        
          Register
        
        
          Contat us

Comment: i want to align the list items to the rite, how do i select them in css and specifically edit them? I also want to make a small page break between navbar and header.

Comment: I want to seperate the list items on the header apart. Theyre stuck to each other. How do i also edit their hover... E.g: When i hover my mouse over them, it seems to turn blue ( the default ) But i want to change that. How?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You are closing the inner `div` before closing the `ul` which is a child of that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are new to HTML and CSS, [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/) would be a great start. I can see that you still have some issues in wrapping your HTML elements (e.g. when to open and close a `<div>` tag. Before proceeding to CSS, it is advisable that you already learned the basics of HTML because you will be using them when putting an attribute that you want to access in CSS (e.g. `id=""`, `class=""`, `name=""`, `type=""`, etc.)

Comment: Hi, i appreciate your concern but rite now ill highlt appreciate an answer.